# How to revert to the default 'compilation-mode' behavior under doom emacs?

Tags: doom, compilation-mode

How can the "compilation" experience in Emacs be reverted to the behavior of a vanilla emacs installation when using [doom emacs](https://github.com/doomemacs/)?

As a long time user of "vanilla" Emacs, I am too used to the previous behavior, and I find myself getting frustrated when, for example, I cannot just switch back to a compilation window which I expect to be the "previous" buffer.

Comment: Onde difference I observed between vanilla Emacs and Doom Emacs with respect to the `*compilation*` buffer is that Doom makes the window that displays the that buffer a **[dedicated window](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html)** that may only display the contents of `*compilation*`.  They probably had a reason for doing that, and I would hesitate to change it without understanding why they did that.

Comment: @g-gundam I myself remember finding it annoying that only allowed a single `*compliation*` was possible at any time.  I can therefore imagine the new behavior to be seen as an improvement.  Unfortunately, I'm just too used to the previous behavior.

Comment: It looks like Doom did that by providing a custom function to [`compilation-buffer-name-function`](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/b395bd5392dd6ca88b230102363797b47b8f6991/lisp/doom-projects.el#L97).  This makes me wonder...  Although you want to be able to get to the `*compilation*` buffer with `previous-buffer` or `next-buffer`, would you be open to using a custom function with a custom keybinding to get there instead?